# registering resources with GenericSetup in Plone 5

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

The page on CSS in the docs http://docs.plone.org/adapt-and-extend/theming/templates_css/css.html#plone-css still suggests using cssregistry.xml, even though the resources are stored in the registry now. Is this the preferred method, as opposed to registry.xml? As far as I can tell it adds them to the plone legacy bundle. Given its name, it sounds like that is something I should be moving away from.

Assuming I don't want to keep using plone legacy bundle, is it bad to add my css/js to the plone bundle or should I create a new bundle for my namespaces?

Comment: Not a simple (AKA confused) task right now. You'll find a very interesting discussion here: https://community.plone.org/t/plone-5-registries-legacy-bundle-implementation-broken-by-design/1122/7

Comment: What are you trying to do? Build a re-usable package or solve single-site problems? Build an add-on that will be useful for the next version of Plone, or get something done quickly. This is a wide-open question with no single answer.

Comment: Fair enough - this if for a re-usable package.

Comment: I think this is all due to a confusion on my part on what the legacy bundle is supposed to be. I assumed it was a legacy genericsetup import, but some a stray doc indicates that the legacy bundle is intended for js that doesn't use requirejs. So I should stick with that for now.